# $4$ equations $4$ unknowns by Gaussian Elimination

Tags: linear-algebra

I've got a question with $4$ points asking me to determine the function:

$(-2,-12), (0,3), (2,-1), (4,9)$

I did this the long way by subtracting all the functions and got the answer:   $$0.6875x^3-2.375x^2+3$$

But in my research I found something called Gaussian Elimination and was wondering if someone could show this solution and explain whats happening so I could learn it. This looks like it would be a lot quicker than what I did and what they expect in class.

I've tried reading these on my own but can't seem to figure out exactly what to do.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianElimination.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha_1... \alpha_4$ be the coefficients of your polynomial e.g. $f(x) =\alpha_1+\alpha_2 x+\alpha_3 x^2 + \alpha_4 x^3$. Then you can use your 4 points as inputs of $x$ and values of $f(x)$ to create a 4x4 matrix listing the coefficients of alphas with potentially a unique solution for the values of the alphas. In this case, the matrix equation would look like this: 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2 & 4 & -8\\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 &  2& 4 &8 \\ 
1 & 4 & 16 & 64
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_1\\ 
\alpha_2\\ 
\alpha_3\\ 
\alpha_4
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
-12\\ 
3\\ 
-1\\ 
9
\end{bmatrix}$$

If you have further questions about creating or solving the matrix, let me know and I can show you some good resources.

Comment: Just a guess, but do I divide the answer matrix by the coefficient matrix?

Comment: Although that is possible by finding what is called in inverse matrix, you can still find the solution a little simpler than that. If you solve from upper left down and to the right by doing typical elimination rules when combing equations you will get what's called an identity matrix on the left with correlates to exact values for alphas on the right. You can plug something like this in wolfram to see what the solution looks like or you can look up videos on YouTube about "Reduced Row Echelon Form".

Comment: Here's how to enter it into wolfram so it can Internet your solution http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C-2%2C4%2C-8%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%2C4%2C8%7D%2C%7B1%2C4%2C16%2C64%7D%7D%7B%7Ba_1%7D%2C%7Ba_2%7D%2C%7Ba_3%7D%2C%7Ba_4%7D%7D%3D%7B%7B-12%7D%2C%7B3%7D%2C%7B-1%7D%2C%7B9%7D%7D

Comment: $$\begin{bmatrix}
alpha_1 & -2 alpha_2 & 4 alpha_3 & -8 alpha_4\\ 
alpha_1 \\ 
alpha_1 & 2 alpha_2 & 4 alpha_3 & 8 alpha_4 \\ 
alpha_1 & 4 alpha_2 & 16 alpha_3 & 64 alpha_4
\end{bmatrix}

=\begin{bmatrix}
-12\\ 
3\\ 
-1\\ 
9
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: How do you solve this though?   Am I supposed to just remove the matrix notations and do them algebraically through elimination?

Comment: That's right! You're asking a lot of great and important questions about this type of mathematics so you might want to research some Linear Algebra basics in your own time. Meanwhile, here is a video demonstrating how to solve a matrix in this form, sorry it's a bit too extensive to type it out step by step from my phone https://youtu.be/9LYVi-n-6Jw

Comment: This is the amazing, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Following Connor's answer to show some of the mechanics.

Going with the cubic solution:

$$f(x) =\alpha_1+\alpha_2 x+\alpha_3 x^2 + \alpha_4 x^3$$

Let's take $(-2,-12)$ and plug it in:

$$f(-2) = -12 = \alpha_1 -2\alpha_2 + 4\alpha_3 - 8 \alpha_4.$$

From here I'd create a row in the augmented matrix with these elements:

$$1, -2, 4, -8, -12$$

Then I'd repeat this process with each point, and end up with a matrix with $5$ columns and $4$ rows.

From here, it's a matter of doing valid operations on the rows to transform the left four columns to the identity matrix.  The fifth column then has the values for $\alpha_i$.